# Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

Tags: ruby, react-native

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5896.png).]

After successfully installed all of the aboves I was going to create react-native app using npx react-native init AwesomeProject comand and faced Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5 error is also given in attached file. please check it and help me to suggest the way to solved.

Comment: Please do provide some more information. What OS are you using? How did you install Ruby? rbenv or RVM? What do you get when you type ruby -v in terminal?

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to upgrade your machines ruby installation from 2.6.8 to 2.7.5.  If you have rbenv installed you can install multiple versions of ruby onto your machine and switch between them.

`rbenv install 2.7.5`

Answer (score 0):

I have followed these instructions to solve this issue:

1. **Homebrew install:** /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   watchman install: brew install watchman
2. **Install Ruby:** followed rbenv Official Github Repo link to install the required version of ruby
3. Install CocoaPods: sudo gem install cocoapods
   CocoaPods in fixed location: sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin ffi cocoa pods

After the environment setup, it works perfectly.

Those users who use the MacBook air M1, Please make sure that your terminal is working on the **Rosetta**

Finder > Go > Utilities > Terminal > GetInfo

[I attached the image for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JziHF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2.6.8 is Mac system Ruby version. So we should install Ruby 2.7.5 manually. We can install it with **Chruby**.

1. `brew install ruby-install chruby`
2. `open -e ~/.zshrc`

   Add configuration commands for Chruby:

   `source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh`

   `source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh`

   `chruby ruby-2.7.5`
3. `ruby-install ruby 2.7.5`
4. check ruby version `ruby -v`

Answer (score 0):

follow only 3 steps:

1. rvm install ruby-2.7.5
2. rvm --default use 2.7.5
3. rvm use system

now close and re-open terminal then check ruby version.  hopefully this will be your expected version  there.